Performance issue - cant fix with pg_plan_hints
I have a query that is stored in a function. It is called via a prepared statement jdbc app.
I have a fix for the query to force an index - but I cant get the "normalized form" required for it to match. Any suggestions ?
Query AS extracted from pg_stat_statements
"(
    select
        registration_date,
        to_char(registration_date, $17)::VARCHAR as x_axis_date,
        to_char(registration_date, upper(adminDateFormat))::VARCHAR as formatted_registration_date,
        count(distinct lead_email) as registered_leads
    from (
        select
            DATE_TRUNC($18,min(eu.create_timestamp) AT TIME ZONE $19 AT TIME ZONE adminTZ) as registration_date,
        --  DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMEZONE(adminTZ, TIMEZONE('PST', min(eu.create_timestamp)))) as registration_date,
            dl.email as lead_email
        from
            client_hierarchy ch
            join dw_lead dl on dl.client_id = ch.sub_client_id
            join dw_lead_user dlu on dlu.lead_id = dl.lead_id
            join event e on dlu.event_id = e.event_id
            join event_user eu on eu.event_user_id = dlu.event_user_id and eu.event_id = dlu.event_id
        where
            ch.client_id = clientId::BIGINT
            and dl.lead_update_timestamp between startDate and endDate -- this will discard leads out of the selected time range
            -- and dl.email not like '%deleted' -- this should not be needed, deleted users are removed
            and eu.create_timestamp between startDate and endDate
            /*and e.event_profile_id <> experienceProfileId*/
            and e.is_active = $20
            and eu.is_deleted = $21
            -- Exclude Golive Data 
            and e.event_profile_id not in (lighthouseProfileId, lighthouseSessionProfileId)
            -- Excluding Top-Level Overall Recurring Webcasts
            AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT $22
              FROM recurring_webcast_metadata rwm
              WHERE rwm.event_id = e.event_id
            )
        group by
            dl.email
    ) as leads_trend
    group by
        registration_date
    order by
        registration_date asc
)"

What is the normalized form that should work here - everything I have tried doesnt work.
Obviously the $1/$2 etc are prepared statemnte parameters ..... but there are others also like ....
adminDateFormat adminTZ clientId
Unclear on why they are not passed as a prepared stmt.
Anyway - not sure what the "normalized" form of this should look like. I have left all the $1, $2 as is .... and changed the other parameters to ? ..... but the query plan doesnt
match when I trace it - returns 0 rows from hint_plan.hints
Current version of hint attempt with normalized code
 
insert into hint_plan.hints values (1,'(
        select
            registration_date,
            to_char(registration_date, $17)::VARCHAR as x_axis_date,
            to_char(registration_date, upper(?))::VARCHAR as formatted_registration_date,
            count(distinct lead_email) as registered_leads
        from (
            select
                DATE_TRUNC($18,min(eu.create_timestamp) AT TIME ZONE $19 AT TIME ZONE ?) as registration_date,
            --  DATE_TRUNC(''DAY'', TIMEZONE(adminTZ, TIMEZONE(''PST'', min(eu.create_timestamp)))) as registration_date,
                dl.email as lead_email
            from
                client_hierarchy ch
                join dw_lead dl on dl.client_id = ch.sub_client_id
                join dw_lead_user dlu on dlu.lead_id = dl.lead_id
                join event e on dlu.event_id = e.event_id
                join event_user eu on eu.event_user_id = dlu.event_user_id and eu.event_id = dlu.event_id
            where
                ch.client_id = clientId::BIGINT
                and dl.lead_update_timestamp between ? and ? -- this will discard leads out of the selected time range
                -- and dl.email not like ''%deleted'' -- this should not be needed, deleted users are removed
                and eu.create_timestamp between ? and ?
                /*and e.event_profile_id <> experienceProfileId*/
                and e.is_active = $20
                and eu.is_deleted = $21
                -- Exclude Golive Data 
                and e.event_profile_id not in (?, ?)
                -- Excluding Top-Level Overall Recurring Webcasts
                AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT $22
                  FROM recurring_webcast_metadata rwm
                  WHERE rwm.event_id = e.event_id
                )
            group by
                dl.email
        ) as leads_trend
        group by
            registration_date
        order by
            registration_date asc
    )', 'myapp','IndexScan(rwm)'
    );


Can you add the version of Postgres and version of pg_hint_plan?

Sure - Postgres 12 (GCP cloud).
1.3.8 for pg_plan_hint
